# Argument "absorber" in g4beamline

Tags: s

How to use "absorber" argument in g4beamline to simulate an asymmetry structure. How to setup innerRadius and outerRadius in safeWindow and absWindow?
Thank you very much.

I tried with absorber but I don't know how to defind innerRadius and outerRadius in safeWindow and absWindow which isnot in Window file which is available before.